# passing multiple variable to one view in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

hello to all I want to pass multiple variables to one view 
this is my `CategoryController.php`

```
    public function site()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('template.sitemap', ['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

and this is `SubCategoryController.php`

```
public function index2(){
    $subcategories =  SubCategory::all();
    return view('template.sitemap',['subcategories'=>$subcategories]);
}
```

this is my route for this action in `web.php`

```
Route::get('sitemap.html','CategoryController@site')->name('sitemap')
Route::get('sitemap.html','SubCategoryController@index2')->name('sitemap');
```

and this is the view i am trying to do this  sitemap.blade.php

```
   @foreach($categories as $category)
      <li><a href="category.html">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
      <ul>
       @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
         <li><a href="category.html">{{$subcategory->category_name->name}</li>
       @endforeach
      </ul>
  @endforeach
```

but i constantly see undefind vairalble
alone they work good
but when i want user both variables seee undefined vairable.

Comment: you must perform a check whether the variable exists or not before echo it as `@if(isset($categories)) @endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site will go to the first route and will never go to your second controller. 
You should rather write.

**Route**

```
 Route::get('sitemap.html','CategoryController@site')->name('sitemap');
```

**Controller**

```
  public function site(){
      $data =  array();
      $data['subcategories']  =  SubCategory::all();
      $data['categories']     =  Category::all();
      return view('template.sitemap',compact("data"));
   }
```

**View**

```
    @foreach($data['categories'] as $category)
    <li><a href="category.html">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
    <ul>
       @foreach($data['subcategories'] as $subcategory)
       <li><a href="category.html">{{$subcategory->category_name->name}}</li>
       @endforeach
    </ul>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write

```
public function site()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $subcategories =  SubCategory::all();
    return view('template.sitemap', compact('categories', 'subcategories');
}
```

or you can eager load this

```
public function site()
{
    $categories = Category::with('subcategories')->get();
    return view('template.sitemap', compact('categories');
}
```

in view

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
  <li><a href="category.html">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
<ul>
    @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
         <li><a href="category.html">{{$subcategory->name}}</li>
    @endforeach   
   </ul>
@endforeach
```