# how do i pass value from different link to one view laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

So I have this view1.php where I want to pass different values from different links to view2.php. 
I manage to pass and get the value, but the css I put in my layout.php just won't work for view2.php. 
I don't know where I'm doing it wrong.
Are there another way to pass different values other than this?

> view1.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')
<div>
    <a href="/pass/6000"> OP 6000 </a>
    <a href="/pass/10000"> OP 10000 </a>
    <a href="/pass/20000"> OP 20000 </a>
</div>
@endsection
```

> web.php

`Route::get('/pass/{id}','User\MyController@postID');`

> MyController.php

```
public function postID($id) {
    return view('user.view2', [
      'id' => $id
    ]);
}
```

> view2.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')
  <div>
    {{$id}}
  </div>
@endsection
```

> layout.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

  <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialize.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/user.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav> </nav>

  <main class="">
    @yield('content')
  </main>

  <footer> </footer>
  @yield('alert')
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `href="css` to `href="/css` or use Laravel's asset helpers. Also `src="/js` instead of `src="js`

Comment: How are "passing values to views" and "CSS not rendering" related? What is your question about?

Comment: Is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837048/12232340

Answer (score 0):

Seems the css is not loading in view2.php. You need to use baseurl to load css.

Example : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/user.css')}}">`

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because when you redirect another view your CSS not load properly.

My advice to you is using the `assets` method.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/materialize.css') }}"  media="screen,projection"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/user.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because the URL of your view2 are `http://something.com/pass/some_id` and you are linking stylesheets by `css/some_css.css` so that, it is searching in the current directory i.e. `pass` so that, the URLs of the stylesheets are becoming like `http://something.com/pass/css/some_css.css`. That's an issue.

If you will use `/css/some_cs.css`, it will try to locate the files from the home directory i.e. the `/` directory, so the URL will become `http://something.com/css/some_css.css` and everything will work perfectly.

else, you should use the helper provided by Laravel 
`{{asset('css/some_css.css')}}`
It will generate URL, where the files are located without fail.

Comment: same for CSS and JS. Start with ````/````